# Algorithm for finding the modular form corresponding to an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

For an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ given by a Weierstrass equation, is there an algorithm for finding the weight 2 cusp form as a $q$-expansion that corresponds to it by the modularity theorem?

Comment: How about computing the points over finite fields to find the trace of the Frobenii, the $a_p$. If you compute enough and know the conductor, you can solve for the coefficients after picking a basis of the space of modular forms of level conductor.

Comment: This is implemented in Sage as $\texttt{E.newform()}$.

Comment: This is answered in [MSE question 2898989](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2898989) "Modular Forms in Pari/GP" and you can look at the source code for `ellan()`

Comment: In Pari/GP you can use mffromell(E) and then mfcoefs to get the q-expansion.